# How to retrieve Mask of Yalung in Satish's Sad Room cave?

Tags: far-cry-4

I've located Satish's Sad Room cave and found a Mask of Yalung which is located behind a locked iron gate.  I've searched the location for a key, and didn't find one, tried shooting and melee striking the gate, and finally placed a C-4 charge beside it and detonated it.  Nothing has worked.  Has anyone figured out how to retrieve the mask from behind the gate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are mask you can't retrieve due to unfortunate placement. You are supposed to either retrieve or destroy the masks. In that case you can shoot it through the gate (I wasn't able to destroy with explosives either).

Comment: Grenades and other explosives will also do the trick. I suggest using a grenade launcher.

Answer (score 5):

When you face the door there will be a chunk of the door missing in the top left corner above the stone. Equip your explosive arrow and shot your arrow through this gap. If done correctly it will destroy it on the first arrow. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

use a molotave cocktail!!   Took me a while to figure it out but there are also some posters that are really hard to reach,  M C does the same with those.